# Laravel long string encrpted but not decrpted

Tags: laravel-5, encryption

$string = encrypt('Shwewewe Wawweter Resouweeces aewend Hydrerer Engineering Grweweoup Co Ltwewed');

$stringdecrpt = decrypt($string);

encrypt working fine but when i decrypt it not decrypting please any one help me i am so tried to find solution

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provides exception in such case of decrypt, try using it and find out what is the error.

```php
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException;

try {
    $decrypted = decrypt($encryptedValue);
} catch (DecryptException $e) {
    //
}
```